# Bash test if an argument exists

Tags: bash, testing, command-line-arguments

I want to test if an augment (e.g. -h) was passed into my bash script or not.

In a Ruby script that would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts "Has -h" if ARGV.include? "-h"
```

How to best do that in Bash?

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash shell script check input argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482377/bash-shell-script-check-input-argument)

Comment: @Thomas -- that checks if any argument exists -- I think this question asks if a specific argument exists

Answer (score 10):

The simplest solution would be:

```
if [[ " $@ " =~ " -h " ]]; then
   echo "Has -h"
fi
```

Comment: While clever, this reports false positives for arguments that are strings embedding the substring ` -h ` (e.g., `my_command "oh gods -h game over"`). The only general-purpose solution is to iterate `getopts` results as detailed below. `</shrug>`

Comment: true! Today I also would endorse getopts. The simple solution is more a wonky hack...

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts h x; do
  echo "has -h";
done; OPTIND=0
```

As  Jonathan Leffler pointed out
OPTIND=0 will reset the getopts list. That's in case the test needs to be done more than once.

Comment: The option is not removed.  The trick to reparsing the argument list is to reset `OPTIND=0` between the `getopts` loops.

Comment: Understood. Verified. Answer corrected. Thanks to Jonathan Leffler for all the tips that lead to this answer.

Comment: Note that for me this outputs "has -h" multiple times, even though `-h` was only specified once as an argument...

Answer (score 2):

It is modestly complex.  The quickest way is also unreliable:

```
case "$*" in
(*-h*) echo "Has -h";;
esac
```

Unfortunately that will also spot "`command this-here`" as having "`-h`".

Normally you'd use `getopts` to parse for arguments that you expect:

```
while getopts habcf: opt
do
    case "$opt" in
    (h) echo "Has -h";;
    ([abc])
        echo "Got -$opt";;
    (f) echo "File: $OPTARG";;
    esac
done

shift (($OPTIND - 1))
# General (non-option) arguments are now in "$@"
```

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to solve this in a straightforward but correct manner, and am just sharing what works for me.

The dedicated function below solves it, which you can use like so:

```sh
if [ "$(has_arg "-h" "$@")" = true ]; then
    # TODO: code if "-h" in arguments
else
    # TODO: code if "-h" not in arguments
fi
```

This function checks whether the first argument is in all other arguments:

```sh
function has_arg() {
    ARG="$1"
    shift
    while [[ "$#" -gt 0 ]]; do
        if [ "$ARG" = "$1" ]; then
            echo true
            return
        else
            shift
        fi
    done
    echo false
}
```