# Testing against -n option in BASH scripts always returns true

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am writing a bash script, in which I am trying to check if there are particular parameters provided. I've noticed a strange (at least for me) behavior of `[ -n arg ]` test. For the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n $1 ]; then
    echo "The 1st argument is of NON ZERO length"
fi

if [ -z $1 ]; then
    echo "The 1st argument is of ZERO length"
fi
```

I am getting results as follows:

1. **with no parameters:**

   ```
   xylodev@ubuntu:~$ ./my-bash-script.sh
   The 1st argument is of NON ZERO length
   The 1st argument is of ZERO length
   ```
2. **with parameters:**

   ```
   xylodev@ubuntu:~$ ./my-bash-script.sh foobar
   The 1st argument is of NON ZERO length
   ```

I've already found out that enclosing `$1` in double quotes gives me the results as expected, but I still wonder **why both tests return true when quotes are not used and the script is called with no parameters?** It seems that `$1` is null then, so `[ -n $1 ]` should return false, shouldn't it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check existence of input argument in a Bash shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482377/check-existence-of-input-argument-in-a-bash-shell-script)

Comment: Related: [Test for non-zero length string in Bash: -n “$var” or “$var”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3869072/6862601).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quote it.

```
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
```

Without the quotes, if `$1` is empty, you execute `[ -n ]`, which is true*, and if `$1` is not empty, then it's obviously true.

* If you give `[` a single argument (excluding `]`), it is always true. (Incidentally, this is a pitfall that many new users fall into when they expect `[ 0 ]` to be false). In this case, the single string is `-n`.

Comment: I missed somehow that in the above case `-n` is considered as a string when no other parameters are provided for the `[` command. Clear now. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: So, what about the following case? It appears to be saying that '1' is null:

    $> b=1; if [ -n "$b" ]; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi
    true

Comment: No @TomRussell - `-n` tests for _Non-zero length_, not _Nullness._

Comment: `[ STRING ]` is actually given as an equivalent to `[ -n STRING ]` in [this table](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html).