# Parameters Control - Bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, if-statement

I have a unix shell script that reads parameter from command line and then exit in case parameter missing. Then i tested with parameter, which is supposed to work fine but it exit with error.
anyone can check please?

SCRIPT:

```
#!/bin/ksh
##########################################################################
#       Remote to upstream servers to check feed files without password  #
#               ELLA YE                                                  #
#               Sept 20 2017                                             #
#               Version 1                                                #
##########################################################################

RUNDIR=/tmp
UPSTREAM_USER="$1"
UPSTREAM_SERVER=$2
UPSTREAM_DIR=$3
FILE_NAME=$4
LOCAL_DIR=$5

echo $5
#if [[ ( "$1" = "" ) || ( "$2 = "" ) || ( "$3" = "" ) || ( "$4" = "" ) || ( "$5 = "" ) ]]
if [ $5 -eq "" ];
then
        echo "Parameter missing"
exit 1;
fi
```

**my command:**

```
./sftpupstream.ksh abc abc.wlb2.nam.nsroot.net . .profile .
```

**result:**

```
.
Parameter missing
bash-4.1$
```

Comment: I would just test that $# is of the size you want :)  empty string should do not get counted in the argument list. so [ $# -eq 5 ]

Comment: The shebang line denotes `ksh` as the interpreter, not `bash`. You likely cannot use bash-only extensions in a Korn shell script.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```sh
if [ -z "$5" ]
  then
    echo "Parameter missing"
    exit 1
fi
```

The -z switch will test if the expansion of "$5" is a null string or not. If it is a null string then the body is executed.

see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482377/check-existence-of-input-argument-in-a-bash-shell-script)

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the top of your script :

```
#!/bin/ksh
if [ $# -ne 5 ]; then
        echo "$((5 - $#)) parameter(s) missing"
        exit 1
    else
        # You code
    fi
```

`$#` return the number of parameters passed to your scripts, so if different to 5 script will exit.

`echo "$((5 - $#))"` will do the maths and output how many parameters are missing out of 5.

Answer (score -1):

What is the error message?

My blind guess is put your vars in quote. "$5"