# How to know if an argument was passed to my bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-arguments

Suppose I have a bash script `scr.sh`. Inside this script I have a variable `$x`. I need to setup the following behavior. If `scr.sh` is called with an argument, as in:

```
./scr.sh 45
```

then I want `x` to be assigned to this value inside my bash script. Otherwise, if there is no command line argument, as in:

```
./scr.sh
```

`x` should be assigned to some default value, which in my case is an environment variable, say `x=$ENVIRONMENT_VAR`.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash shell script check input argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482377/bash-shell-script-check-input-argument)

Comment: You can check for `[[ $# == 1 ]]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash test if an argument exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221271/bash-test-if-an-argument-exists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this to set a default value:

```
x="${1:-$ENVIRONMENT_VAR}"
```

---

```
${parameter:-word}
   Use Default Values. If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is
   substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.
```

Comment: I wish more people understood how powerful the `${parameter:[-+?=]word}` paradigm is. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter Is there a link where `${parameter:[-+?=]word}` is explained?

Comment: @becko : `http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html` is the best I know of. Good luck to all.

Comment: You want to use `${1-$ENVIRONMENT_VAR}` in case the empty string (`./scr.sh ""`) is a valid argument that should not be replaced with the value of `ENVIRONMENT_VAR`.

Comment: @becko They are all documented in the man page, under Parameter Expansion.

Answer (score 0):

While this has been answered perfectly well by @Cyrus, I'd like to offer a slight variation of the `${parameter:-word}` approach, namely:

```
: ${x:=${1-$ENVIRONMENT_VAR}}
```

This allows you to go one step further and submit an override functionality on calling the script. Below you see the three invariants one can have using this approach:

```
$ ./src.sh
x=42
$ ./src.sh 8
x=8
$ x=2 ./src.sh 8
x=2
```

The script used for the above output:

```
$ cat ./src.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ENVIRONMENT_VAR=42
: ${x:=${1-$ENVIRONMENT_VAR}}
echo "x=${x}"
```